# Active Data/Script on Facebook Wall Post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-wall

i want to post on Facebook Wall
but i just dont want to post simple text/image or a URL
i want to post a active code, that will get some kind of data/information from my server and display it in on user wall, the user of my application would get data based on the current statstics.

So, How can i post a SCRIPT wether AJAX, jQuery ,JS or any other which will run whenever the page is loaded and display the desired info, which my FB App will provide to user via the server.

please HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot post scripts on Facebook wall with or without API.

Comment: 'any other way to get LIVE DATA????' If you are asking about a facebook POST which change the values accourding to an external source, then the answer is NO.

Comment: I think what you want to implement is show some real-time data to some  users once they logged in to Facebook? If it is the case, then create a Facebook application to get data (and add it to a page as a tab if you want ). then ask users to visit your app or page.

Comment: thnks Kasun for clearing that up, i know about visting page or app way.
can we add some kind of widget or tag `<embedded>` content like a flash content or a WIDGET on user wall??

Comment: according to my knowledge the answer is no.